# Replace missing identifier with a unique value using dplyr::replace_na

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, uniqueidentifier

I'm tracking citations, some of which lack a unique identifier (PMID). I would like to replace NAs in PMID with a unique proqunit from package{ids} using dplyr::replace_na.

```
refs <- structure(list(Author = c("Aubrey", "Azrin", "Azrin", "Azrin", 
"Azrin", "Szapocznik"), Year = c(1998L, 1994L, 1996L, 1994L, 
2001L, 2003L), PMID = c(NA, NA, 8561763L, 7993330L, NA, 23731415L
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The code below replaces the NAs in PMID with the same proquint, rather than with the intended unique value for each missing PMID.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ids)

    refs_with_uniqueID <- refs %>% 
      mutate(PMID = replace_na(PMID, ids::proquint(n = 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware that `dplyr` has a `replace_na` function.  Perhaps you mean `tidyr`? From `?tidyr::replace_na`:

> `replace`: ...If ‘data’ is a vector, a single value used for replacement.

`tidyr::replace_na` replaces all the NAs with the same value.  To use unique values for each NA, try

```
set.seed(123)
refs %>% 
  mutate(PMID = replace(PMID, is.na(PMID), ids::proquint(n = sum(is.na(PMID)))))
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Author      Year PMID       
#   <chr>      <int> <chr>      
# 1 Aubrey      1998 hokiv-solav
# 2 Azrin       1994 kofuf-vamat
# 3 Azrin       1996 8561763    
# 4 Azrin       1994 7993330    
# 5 Azrin       2001 zagaf-bovon
# 6 Szapocznik  2003 23731415
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *row_number*, instead of *id::proquint*:

```
library(dplyr)

refs_with_uniqueID <- refs %>% 
  mutate(PMID = if_else(is.na(PMID),
                        paste0("uid_", row_number()),
                        as.character(PMID)))
refs_with_uniqueID
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#    Author      Year PMID    
#   <chr>      <int> <chr>   
# 1 Aubrey      1998 uid_1   
# 2 Azrin       1994 uid_2   
# 3 Azrin       1996 8561763 
# 4 Azrin       1994 7993330 
# 5 Azrin       2001 uid_5   
# 6 Szapocznik  2003 23731415
```

---

**Note:** Both methods, *row_number* and *id::proquint*, will not guarantee that generated new ids do not already exist in non-NA rows.