# creating unique IDs based on already ID column

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose my df looks like:

```
test <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,NA, NA, 6, 8, 9))
```

I would like to fill my NA with unique values. More exactly NAs should be filled with numbers not occuring in the IDs columns ( in the example: not using 1:4 or 6:8)
More over, each NA value should have a unique ID, so not repating e.g. 5 twice. So best solution here would be

```
test <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5, 10, 6, 8, 9))
```

eventhough I also happy with e.g.

```
test <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,10, 11, 6, 8, 9))
```

I found this one:
[Replace missing identifier with a unique value using dplyr::replace_na](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488122/replace-missing-identifier-with-a-unique-value-using-dplyrreplace-na)

but as in the second answer it is stated:
"Note: Both methods, row_number and id::proquint, will not guarantee that generated new ids do not already exist in non-NA rows."

which is exactly what I need.

A dplyr answer is highly appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with your second option so as to avoid complications when the existing `ID` is not sequential.

We can find the `max` of the `ID` value and add next values to it and `replace` it in place of `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate(ID = replace(ID, is.na(ID), 
                      max(ID, na.rm = TRUE) + seq_len(sum(is.na(ID)))))

#  ID
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3
#4  4
#5 10
#6 11
#7  6
#8  8
#9  9
```

In base R, this can be written as -

```
mx <- max(test$ID, na.rm = TRUE)
na_val <- is.na(test$ID)
test$ID[na_val] <- mx + seq_len(sum(na_val))
test
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setdiff` with `replace`:

```r
library(dplyr)
test |> 
  mutate(ID2 = replace(ID, is.na(ID), setdiff(seq_along(ID), ID)))

#   ID ID2
# 1  1   1
# 2  2   2
# 3  3   3
# 4  4   4
# 5 NA   5
# 6 NA   7
# 7  6   6
# 8  8   8
# 9  9   9
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
test %>%
 mutate(ID2 = if_else(is.na(ID), cumsum(is.na(ID)) + max(ID, na.rm = TRUE), ID))

   ID ID2
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
5  NA  11
6  NA  12
7   6   6
8   8   8
9   9   9
10 NA  13
11 10  10
12 NA  14
```

A slightly more complex sample dataset:

```
test <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,NA, NA, 6, 8, 9, NA, 10, NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
idx <- is.na(test$ID)

test$ID[idx] <- seq(max(test$ID, na.rm = TRUE) + 1, length = sum(idx))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rle`

```
> transform(test, ID=with(rle(ID),
+                         replace(values, is.na(values), max(values, na.rm=TRUE) + 
+                                   sequence(sum(is.na(values))))))
  ID
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5 10
6 11
7  6
8  8
9  9
```

or adding `cumsum` of NA's to `max`

```
> within(test, {na <- is.na(ID); ID[na] <- cumsum(na)[na] + max(ID, na.rm=TRUE); rm(na)})
  ID
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5 10
6 11
7  6
8  8
9  9
```

Answer (score 0):

A *base* Variant using the integer ID's, to subset a vector of possible ID's to be used to fill up the missing values.

```
i <- is.na(test$ID)
test$ID[i] <- seq_len(nrow(test))[-test$ID[!i]][seq_len(sum(i))]
#test$ID[i] <- setdiff(seq_len(nrow(test)), test$ID)[seq_len(sum(i))] # Alternative

test
#  ID
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3
#4  4
#5  5
#6  7
#7  6
#8  8
#9  9
```

Simple Versions, but will give a Warning, when the given ID's are not in the range of 1 to nrow.

```
i <- is.na(test$ID)
test$ID[i] <- seq_len(nrow(test))[-test$ID[!i]]

i <- is.na(test$ID)
test$ID[i] <- setdiff(seq_len(nrow(test)), test$ID)
```